# Accessing Mulit-multi dimensional array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

I hate to post this but I am on a time crunch and need some help with accessing the values in this massive multidiminsional array. After staying up all night I have no more brain power or stamina to play around with it any more. So can someone please help me with a set of nested for loops to get at these values?! Thank you all in advance.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [120] => Array
                (
                    [field_1_textbox_text] => Panel 1
                    [field_2_textbox_text] => p1
                    [field_3_wysiwyg_content] => Pane 1
                    [field_4_textbox_text] => P1
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [121] => Array
                (
                    [field_1_textbox_text] => Panel 2
                    [field_2_textbox_text] => p2
                    [field_3_wysiwyg_content] => Panel 2
                    [field_4_textbox_text] => p2
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [122] => Array
                (
                    [field_1_textbox_text] => Panel 3
                    [field_2_textbox_text] => p3
                    [field_3_wysiwyg_content] => panel 3333
                    [field_4_textbox_text] => p3
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($array as $key => $arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $key => $arr) {
        echo $key, PHP_EOL;
        foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
            echo $key, ': ', $value, PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Didn't understand the question.
You think - $array[0][120]['field_1_textbox_text']?
Or what?
For each dimension there is one loop.
If I have 2D array I have foreach loop inside other foreach loop. In 3D array, you will have foreach loop inside other fooreach loop which is in another foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* foreach example 4: multi-dimensional arrays */
$a = array();
$a[0][0] = "a";
$a[0][1] = "b";
$a[1][0] = "y";
$a[1][1] = "z";

foreach ($a as $v1) {
  foreach ($v1 as $v2) {
    echo "$v2\n";
  }
}
```

Read that http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php or use recursity function